# Theme the "Add to cart" form on the product display page

Tags: 7, commerce, theming

I have a Drupal Commerce project setup on top of D7-22. I've overridden the template file for my product display (`node--product-display.tpl.php`), and have managed to render the product fields, as well as the Add-to-cart form with all of the attributes. I know that `<?php print render($content)?>` will actually render the `<form>` for the attributes and Add-to-Cart button, but I would like to customize the HTML layout of the form and add some other elements to it. For example:

1. I'd like to position the *Add to Wishlist* button next to the *Add to Cart* button
2. I'd like to add some HTML next to one of the attribute fields that is rendered (the Size select box).

Using the Devel module, I was able to pick up fields like `product:commerce_price` and `product:sku`, but none of the attributes or buttons within the actual `<form>`. I'm currently using jQuery to inject HTML into the form...but it's a hack am not all that comfortable with pushing into production.

Is there any way in my `tpl.php` file to print out the form attributes, quantity textbox and buttons individually?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start on your first form alter for add to cart:

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // Add to cart form overrides
  if(substr($form_id, 0, 30) == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form'){
    kpr($form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit the "add to cart" form you can use `hook_form_alter()` or edit the function `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form()` in `commerce_cart` module. In there you can add a second submit button called "wishlist" and add the HTML to the attribute widget. The `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form()` function is quite long but it should be doable.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've had a look through `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form()` and it is a bit overwhelming. I'll look through the functions and see if there's a way to achieve my desired output. Wouldn't want to do this in the event of the Drupal Commerce module itself being updated.

Comment: I've never attempted a `hook_form_alter()` before, but I guess now's as good a time as any to start. Do you have any tips for me?